# Combine Relationship and Node in Neo4j Query Return List

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am looking to query Neo4j and come up with a list of connected nodes and the relationship of those connected nodes. More specifically, I am looking to have the results returned in a single list.

For example, consider the following graph:

```
(user1)-[FOLLOWING]->(user2)
(user1)-[REQUESTED]->(user3)
```

I am hoping to get a return value back from the query that looks something like (it does not need to look exactly like this, but hopefully something that is close and easy to parse):

```
{
  displayName: "User 2",
  username: "user2",
  ... Other properties from the node ...
  relationshipType: "FOLLOWING"
}
-----
{
  displayName: "User 3",
  username: "user3",
  ... Other properties from the node ...
  relationshipType: "REQUESTED"
}
```

I have tried a lot of different queries and gotten close but nothing is quite right.

For example, I tried:

```
MATCH path = (:User {user_id: "user1id"})-[:REQUESTED|FOLLOWING]->(:User)
WITH collect(DISTINCT path) as paths
WITH [p IN paths | {
    nodes: [n IN nodes(p) | n.display_name],
    usernames: [n IN nodes(p) | n.username],
    rels: [r IN relationships(p) |type(r)]
  }] as paths
UNWIND paths as result
RETURN result
SKIP 0
LIMIT 3
```

Which returns:

```
{
  display: ["User 1", "User 2"],
  usernames: ["user1", "user2"],
  rels: ["FOLLOWING"]
}
-----
{
  display: ["User 1", "User 3"],
  usernames: ["user1", "user3"],
  rels: ["REQUESTED"]
}
```

I have a couple questions about the query I posted above.

1. Is there a way to reduce the results down further to get it closer to what I am looking for?
2. Is there a more efficient way to perform this query than what I have above?

Something else I have tried is:

```
MATCH (:User {user_id: "user1id"})-[r:REQUESTED|FOLLOWING]->(users:User)
WITH r, collect(users) AS theUsers
WITH [u IN theUsers | {
    displayName: u.display_name,
    username: u.username
  }] as projectedUsers, r
RETURN type(r), projectedUsers
```

Which returns a table with two columns, but I am unsure if it is guaranteed that the values match up since I have done some manipulation of the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Cypher request returns a node, the result will contain all the properties of that node. There is no need to generate your own data structure for all the properties (unless a different specific structure is really needed - but it does not look like you have one in mind). *When using the neo4j Browser UI, use the `Table` or `Text` view to see the properties.*

Also, it is not clear what kind of result you are trying to get, but here are some possible answers.

1. Get all desired relationships between `User` nodes, then return for each relationship its type and (the properties of) all `User` nodes involved (in outbound-relationship order):

   ```
   MATCH (a:User)-[r:REQUESTED|FOLLOWING]->(b:User)
   RETURN TYPE(r) AS t, a, b
   ```
2. Get all desired relationships between `User` nodes, then return for each relationship type (the properties of) all distinct `User` nodes involved.

   ```
   MATCH p=(:User)-[r:REQUESTED|FOLLOWING]->(:User)
   UNWIND NODES(p) AS us
   RETURN TYPE(r) AS t, COLLECT(DISTINCT us) AS users
   ```

Comment: You are correct, I was not clear on describing what I am looking for. However, I think your suggestion #1 is the solution I need. To be sure, here is what I am looking to get from this query: 

User 1 has relationships with several other users. I am looking to get a list of those users and the corresponding relationship (either REQUESTED or FOLLOWING).

I had actually tried something similar to #1 before, but was unsure if I can trust the ordering of the rows in the returned table. If I get t[n] and b[n], can I be sure they correspond to the same user/relationship result?

Comment: A `MATCH <pattern>` clause actually generates a separate _row_ for each instance of the pattern in the DB. Each row contains all the variable values that belong to the same match. If you are filling separate lists from the row data, it is up to you to make sure you maintain the same indexing. It looks like your 2 queries were doing that.